# Global functions behave improperly with Python Unittests

Tags: python, global, python-unittest

I am new to unittest. I want to log the return values of the function I am testing to disk so that I can run some offline processing on it later. The problem is that the logging function that is a global function does not get detected. For the example below, the error says that
`NameError: name '_TranslateTestCase___log_test_values' is not defined`

The code is

```
import unittest
import pickle
def ___log_test_values(values):
    with open('/tmp/test_values.bin', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(pickle.dumps(values))

class TranslateTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_word_starting_with_vowel(self):
        global ___log_test_values
        return_value = 'apple'
        ___log_test_values(return_value)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

How do I make sure that the `___log_test_values` function is recognized correctly in this code?

Comment: Why did you name your log function with two leading underscores?

Comment: No real reason, I'm going to deploy the code where the name space isn't in my control so thought of coming with a unique name that shouldn't clash

Comment: Names with two leading underscores are mangled

Answer (score -1):

##### Python globals() built-in function

A method to call the global function `___log_test_values()` from your method `test_word_starting_with_vowel` of the class `TranslateTestCase` is by the [globals()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) function.

`globals()` returns a list of dictionaries - *this list of dictionaries is used to implement the current module namespace* - and every element of the dictionary is a couple key-value where:

- the key is a name available in the namespace of the module
- the value is a reference to the object pointed by the key. By this reference it is possible to call a function defined in the current module.

##### The list returned by globals() in your code

You can print the content of the list returned by the function `globals()` by adding the following *for loop* to your method `test_word_starting_with_vowel`:

```
def test_word_starting_with_vowel(self):
    ...
    for elem in globals():
        print(f"{elem}: points to {globals()[elem]}")
    ...
```

you obtain the following output:

```
__name__: points to __main__
__doc__: points to None
__package__: points to None
__loader__: points to <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f2e5744b048>
__spec__: points to None
__annotations__: points to {}
__builtins__: points to <module 'builtins' (built-in)>
__file__: points to </path/of/the/module>
__cached__: points to None
unittest: points to <module 'unittest' from '/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/__init__.py'>
___log_test_values: points to <function ___log_test_values at 0x7f2e5746fe18>
TranslateTestCase: points to <class '__main__.TranslateTestCase'>
```

In the previous output you can see the function `___log_test_values` and the address in memory where it is allocated:

```
___log_test_values: points to <function ___log_test_values at 0x7f2e5746fe18>
```

This proofs that the function is accessible for the code of the method `test_word_starting_with_vowel`.

##### Use globals() as workaround

By the list returned by `globals()` you can access to the  `___log_test_values()` function.
Modify your code as follows:

```
___log_test_values(return_value) --> globals()['___log_test_values'](return_value)
```

So your code will become:

```
import unittest
import pickle
def ___log_test_values(values):
    with open('/tmp/test_values.bin', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(pickle.dumps(values))

class TranslateTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_word_starting_with_vowel(self):
        global ___log_test_values
        return_value = 'apple'
        #___log_test_values(return_value)
        globals()['___log_test_values'](return_value)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```